# Loop through collection based on product name

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm only a few hours new to shopify and liquid in general.

I have categories that will have the same name as their main product.

What I would like to do is dynamically determine the collection name by assigning the product.handle to a variable called multi and looping through that collection.

So for example, for a product named 'shampoo' I want to assign the var multi to equal the shampoo collection.

Then I will do

```
{% for prod in collections.multi.products %}
        ## Display ##  
{% endfor %}
```

This isn't working right now by putting the variable there but it works if instead of the variable I put the collection name(as expected)

I assume it's an issue with how I'm assigning it using

```
{% assign multi = product.handle %}
```

but I'm not sure exactly how this should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct syntax, the [] are important:

```
{% assign multi = "shampoo" %}
{% for product in collections[multi].products %}
    ## Display ##
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah great!, do you happen to have any good resources you would recommend?

Comment: @adanot [See this page in the Shopify docs](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle#attributes-handle). It explains how/when to use square bracket and dot notation. If you want to use a variable to access a collection, you need to use square brackets.